# installing mechanize with easy_install

Tags: python, mechanize, easy-install

I just got easy_install downloaded but i'm having problems installing mechanize, should I be addressing site-packages at any point. In the first try below, i got an error. in the second try below, i got command not found which is wierd since I know for sure that it downloaded.

```
names-computer:~ names$ cd /Users/names/Desktop/
names-computer:~/Desktop names$ sh /Users/names/Desktop/mechanize-0.1.9-py2.5.egg
/Users/names/Desktop/mechanize-0.1.9-py2.5.egg: /Users/names/Desktop/mechanize-0.1.9-py2.5.egg: cannot execute binary file

names-computer:~/Desktop names$ easy_install mechanize
-bash: easy_install: command not found
```

Comment: With ActivePython, all you have to do is run "pypm install mechanize". No need to install other programs (ActivePython also includes easy_install/pip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OS X, Python interpreter instances are typically installed as so-called Framework builds which means that there is a `bin` directory within the framework which is typically (but not always) the installation destination for python scripts, such as `easy_install`.  If you are not using the Apple-supplied python (in /usr/bin/) which has its own `easy_install` instance there, you should ensure that the framework bin directory of the desired python is on your shell search PATH and precedes `/usr/bin`.  In particular, if you are using the python installed by the python.org installer, your PATH should look something like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

That ensures that the proper `easy_install` will be found first.  If you are using a MacPorts python, it should look like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

EDIT: By the way, the egg that you downloaded appears to be for Python 2.5 and judging from a previous question, you may be wanting to use it with python 2.6.  If you just use the command

```
$ easy_install mechanize
```

it should automatically download the proper egg, if available, or the source and do the necessary build and install steps.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer... I eventually used this one to get it solved.

Answer (score 11):

```
apt-get install python-setuptools
```

This command will install `easy_install` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to download mechanize to install it with easy_install. You just go:

```
/path/to/easy_install mechanize
```

Your problem is that you don't actually call easy_install.

```
bash: easy_install: command not found
```

That only works if easy_install is installed for the standard Python on your system. evidently you installed it for some other python. Figure out where you actually installed it, and call it with the path. Done!

Answer (score 1):

`mechanize-0.1.9-py2.5.egg` is just a zipped file. Furthermore, you don't need to download the egg manually. `easy_install` will automatically pull down the code for you and install it.

You can install easy_install with [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py), a bootstrap script they provide.